# Is the annotation cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: acme-issuer enough to generate a TLS certificate?

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

From the `cert-manager` doc: adding the annotation `cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: acme-issuer` to an `Ingress` object should trigger the shim, request a certificate to this issuer, and store the certificate (without any namespace ?) (with which name?).

I tried this and it does nothing. Adding a `tls:` section to the yaml definition of the `Ingress` does trigger the shim, request a certificate and store it in the same namespace as the `Ingress`.

This means the doc is incorrect, or should it really work without a `tls:` section ?

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: acme-issuer
spec:
  acme:
    email: user@example.com
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: example-issuer-account-key
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: acme-issuer
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: my-ingress-name
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  rules:
  - host: some.domain.eu
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-service-name
          servicePort: 5000
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - some.domain.eu
    secretName: secret-storage-key-for-tls-cert
```

Answer (score 1):

If you created the issuer correctly, then you need to create a Certificate, so the issuer can issue the certificate using the information you have in the Certificate resource, and populate the secret:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: certname
spec:
  secretName: secretName
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
  commonName: <the CN>
  dnsNames:
  - <name>
```

Once you have this resource, it should create a secret containing the TLS certificates, and store it in `secretName`.

Comment: The idea is to use the shim to automatically create the certificates. Not to create them manually. Is this what you suggest ?

Comment: The certificate resource provides the parameters to create the actual certificate. How can the issuer create the certificates without knowing the CN and dns names?

Comment: The Ingress does specify the dns names (host in rules). The CN could have been specified by an annotation or a settings, but it seems there is no information on it. So the Shim is not able to produce such certificates, and you have to create them manually. This answers my question. Ty for the clarification.

Comment: If there is a way to automate certificate creation I am not aware of it. This works pretty well though, especially if you use it to manage the certificates other than just letsencrypt tls. I have a ca authority managing several backend certs with this along with the front-end tls certs and having a separate certificate resource helps.

Comment: The ingress shim automatically creates certificates from an ingress with a specific annotation (and tls section as per my question). This does work fine. http://docs.cert-manager.io/en/release-0.7/tasks/issuing-certificates/ingress-shim.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm using like you, and that create my TLS ok. But the name of `privateKeySecretRef` is igual `ClusterIssuer` name. The tls section is needed on `ingress`.

Using:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    # The ACME server URL
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    # Email address used for ACME registration
    email: my@email.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
```

Chek the certificate status to debug:

```
kubectl get certificate -o wide
```

If the status `CertificateRequest`

```
kubectl get CertificateRequest -o wide
```

Comment: I'm not sure i understand.

Answer (score 0):

i do not know if you resolved your issue but try to check the following:

- Check if your ingressClass is indeed `nginx` (`kubectl get ingressClass`)
- If you are using only one ingressClass and there is no other ingress-controller installed on your cluster you may not need to specify the class name
- Also which version of cert-manager are you using? I know the annotations has been changed, so if you have a very old cert-manager, the annotation may not be the correct one.
- Once you create the ingress, check if you have an acme-pod and ingress created for the HTTP01 challenge verification and also check the status of the `certificate`, `CertificateRequest`, `Order` and `Challenge` ( e.g: `kubectl describe certificate <your_certificate_object>`)
- Also check on the cert-manager logs to see if there any other issues happening.